# to get an alert every time rsi crosses up starting from a certain point?

Tags: pine-script

I want to fire an alert every time RSI is crossing up starting from a certain point, let's say if that point is rsi 50, I want it to shoot not only when it crosses 50 but also 51, 52, 53 and so on

I've managed to make it work with this code right here, I just want to know if there is more effective way to code this, otherwise I'll have to code all the way to RSI, 100

```
rsiAlert = ta.crossover(rsi, 50) or ta.crossover(rsi, 51) or ta.crossover(rsi, 52) or ta.crossover(rsi, 53) or ta.crossover(rsi, 48) or ta.crossover(rsi, 54) or ta.crossover(rsi, 55) or ta.crossover(rsi, 56) or ta.crossover(rsi, 57) or ta.crossover(rsi, 58) or ta.crossover(rsi, 59)

alertcondition(condition=rsiAlert,
     message="RSI crossed")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use ta.crossover in a loop or you will have strange result.
But you can detect every time the RSI is crossing each point from 50 to 100 with a loop :

```
//@version=5
indicator("RSI")
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 20)

rsiAlert = false
for i = 50 to 100
    if rsi[1] < i and rsi > i
        rsiAlert := true
        break

plot(rsi,"rsi",color=rsiAlert?color.green:color.blue)
```

Comment: thanks alot, i was looking for something exactly like this.